# Programmatic Theme Change Not Working

Tags: android, xml, android-theme

My app loads in a bit of data to start, it takes a couple of seconds so I would like a Splash Screen to display for this time.

All I can see to make sure I do is use `setTheme` before the `super.onCreate`, which I am doing, but as it loads the MainActivity the background is the splash screen and the actionbar has the splash screen image squashed into it.

Here is my styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/background_portrait</item>
    </style>

    <style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/splashscreen</item>
    </style>
```

In my AndroidManifest.xml I have `android:theme="@style/SplashTheme"`

SplashScreen.java runs all the code that takes time, then switches to MainActivity.java where I have -

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

What am I missing? It also seems the splashscreen background is now a background for other things, like some TextViews and the action bar?

Thanks for any help offered.

**EDIT** Also, the code in the splash screen xml doesn't run.  It just loads the background and on completion, loads the Main Activity?

The SplashScreen.java has -

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);

        Log.i("Splash Screen", "loading");

        mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

        // code that takes time
```

The activity_splash_screen.xml is -

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/splashscreen"
    tools:context="com.androidandyuk.bikersbestfriend.SplashScreen">

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="32dp"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id"></com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Don't put a drawable in `android:windowBackground` and then again in the layout background, it will be drawn twice, that's wasted performance. ***///*** I think that the `code that takes time` is so quick the ads don't even get loaded. ***///*** Why do you switch themes at runtime? In manifest you can define theme per activity.

Comment: Thanks, yes, I'd actually found setting the theme in the manifest, so done that. Have removed the call to draw background a second time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `android:background` in a theme. Anything that doesn't have a background will inherit this one.

You meant to set `android:windowBackground`.

Comment: Would you know also why it doesn't actually show what is in activity_splash_screen.xml?  It just shows the background, no other layers. Thanks.

Comment: @AndyCr15 Post the layer drawable and any nested drawables as well at the end of your question.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've put in the splash screen java and xml, is that what you needed?

Comment: @AndyCr15 You mentioned layers, I thought `@drawable/splashcreen` is a `LayerDrawable` and that it doesn't work as expected, is that the case?

Comment: What I mean is, I don't believe any of the commands in activity_splash_screen.xml ever get executed.  For example, I try changing the background to a different image, it doesn't show.

Comment: `I don't believe` Engeneers never believe. Engineers verify. Put some logging in there and check logcat. Make sure SplachActivity is the activity launched at start, check the manifest.

Comment: Thanks.  I have various bits of logging dotted through, showing it's taking the route I expect. SplashScreen.java is called, I see onCreate happening, you can see above this  setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen); and then I see onPostCreate being used, followed by MainActivity onCreate being used. Logically I know it's not actually using activity_splash_screen as I've set a different background in it, which never loads.